# Choose date range based on priority

Tags: sql, sas

I am facing a bit of dead end with the logic. Thought to post in on the forum to seek help.

I have the following datasets.

```
data have1;
input case action_in_date action_out_date priority;
cards;
100 28-MAY-2015 29SEP2015 02
100 04-SEP-2015 27NOV2015 03
100 27-NOV-2015 17SEP2016 04
;
run;

data have2;
input case post_date amount;
cards;
100 18-SEP-2015 250
100 19-SEP-2015 100
100 30-NOV-2015 300
;
run;
```

Now, the post date in first 2 rows (18-SEP-2015 and 19-SEP-2015)  in have2 dataset have a post date which falls between two date ranges in have1 dataset. i e. between  28-MAY-2015 and 29SEP2015 and 04-SEP-2015 and  27NOV2015. But i want the money to be allocated to highest priority. ie between 04-SEP-2015 and  27NOV2015 which has a priority 03. The output i am looking for is below

/*output;*/
100 04-SEP-2015 27NOV2015 03 350
100 27-NOV-2015 17SEP2016 04 300
;

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Could this be a solution to your problem? (not to sure I fully understand the problem)

```
proc sql;
create table allocation as
select b.case, a.action_in_date, a.action_out_date, a.priority, b.post_date, b.amount
from have1 a RIGHT JOIN have2 b
on a.case=b.case and a.action_in_date<=b.post_date<=a.action_out_date
group by b.case, b.post_date
having a.priority=max(a.priority);
quit;
```

Here is a view on the allocation dataset:

[image]

By the way, I propose this code to create have1 and have2:

```
data have1;
informat action_in_date date9. action_out_date date9.;
format action_in_date date9. action_out_date date9.;
input case action_in_date action_out_date priority;
cards;
100 28MAY2015 29SEP2015 02
100 04SEP2015 27NOV2015 03
100 27NOV2015 17SEP2016 04
;
run;

data have2;
informat post_date date9.;
format post_date date9.;
input case post_date amount;
cards;
100 18SEP2015 250
100 19SEP2015 100
100 30NOV2015 300
;
run;
```